# how to put IClientChannel Object in ASP.Net Website Session When using State Server?

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, session, serialization

The problem is I have 2 IIS Servers working as Web Farm and using third Server as State Server for Session Handling between Web Farm Servers.
The Website hosted on these IIS Server calls WCF Webservice I use this Code to connect to Webservice:

```
        NetTcpBinding binding = new NetTcpBinding();
        binding.CloseTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 10, 0);
        binding.OpenTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 10, 0);
        binding.ReceiveTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 10, 0);
        binding.SendTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 10, 0);
        binding.PortSharingEnabled = true;

        EndpointAddress address = new EndpointAddress("net.tcp://x.x.x.x/TestService.svc");
        ChannelFactory<ICustomer> channel = new ChannelFactory<ICustomer>(binding, address);
        channel.Credentials.Windows.ClientCredential.Domain = "test.com";
        channel.Credentials.Windows.ClientCredential.UserName = "usr";
        channel.Credentials.Windows.ClientCredential.Password = "pass";

        var proxy = channel.CreateChannel();
```

Everything is working fine. The problem is I need to put the webservice Proxy in the ASP.net Website Session Knowing that I'm using State Server so the object which I put in the Session must be Serializable. The question is how to make the 'proxy' variable serializable so I can put it in the Session of the State Server. please note that I used this code :

```
       Session["proxy"] = proxy;
```

And I got this error Message :

> Unable to serialize the session state. In 'StateServer' and
>   'SQLServer' mode, ASP.NET will serialize the session state objects,
>   and as a result non-serializable objects or MarshalByRef objects are
>   not permitted. The same restriction applies if similar serialization
>   is done by the custom session state store in 'Custom' mode.

Thank you guys for your help in Advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not create serializable object that has only information you want to transfer?
 Obviously there is non serializable returned from  `channel.CreateChannel();`

**Upadate:** Coppied from comment of OP
Problem Solved by Creating new Class that Implements `DataContract`, `ClientBase<DataContract>` and `ISerializable`. Then Define the properties that define the Object and put it in Dictionary and when Deserialize and retrieve it from Dictionary.

Comment: The problem is not with the information transfer. the problem is I want to put the proxy in session so it could be used by All Web Farm Servers because I am using Round Robin Load Balancer.

Comment: Absolutely, but you cannot put non serializable objects into session, and since error message indicates that this is the case, you might want to put all relevant info into different object serialize it and then later deserialize and reinitialize (if it's possible) actual object from that data.

Comment: Any idea what is the info of Channel which could be

Comment: Check what constructor overrides and settable properties it has. These are ones you will be able to set after deserialization, if these are not sufficient, look for different way to solve this.

Comment: The proxy which I want to put in Session is of
 System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.__TransparentProxy
type I can't create an object of this type I can't even reach the properties of this type of object I guess I'm stuck

Comment: Check the interfaces that __TransparentProxy is implementing. There should be a way to make your custom proxy that you could serialize.

Comment: Do you think I can use AppFabric as Shared Cache for all Web Farm Servers and put the Service Proxy in Shared Cache?

Comment: @user3607778 sorry never used AppFabric.

Comment: Problem Solved buy Create new Class that Implements DataContract, ClientBase<DataContract> and ISerializable
Then Define the properties that define the Object and put it in Dictionary and when Deserialize retrieve it from Dictionary.
Thank you very much.